# Nulling out final variable

Tags: java, null, final

Why is the following code possible? (Just an example I just came up with while working on other code)

```
public String getLogIdentifierFromFile(final File file) {
    //this.file = null; //Gives compiler error as obviously expected
    nullify(file);
    return "";
}

public void nullify(Object object) {
    object = null;
}
```

And how can I ensure that the `final` from the top function actually has an effect? This time it is me making the `nullify` method, but it can also be anyone's code that my method needs to call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code doesn't do what you think it does.

`final` applies to the reference. Your code nulls out a **non-`final` copy** of the original `final` reference. [The copy is taken when you call `nullify()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/367273)

If you examine `file` after calling `nullify()`, you will observe that it remains unchanged.

Thus, this isn't a loophole in how `final` works.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `final File file` make only the references as final. This is to ensure that you do not reassign value to this variable accidentally.

In your code `object = null; // 'object' is not marked as a final reference. Hence it works`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `object` is not `final` in your second method.

So:

```
public String getLogIdentifierFromFile(final File file) {
    //Have a final reference to file
    //Pass it into nullify
    nullify(file);
    //Reference to file is unchanged
    return "";
}
```

And:

```
public void nullify(Object object) {
    //get a reference to some object
    //set it to null
    object = null;
}
```

Think of this as `getLogIdentifierFromFile` is passing a business card with the details of `file` to `nullify` and then `nullify` is scratching off the address on the card.

This does not affect where `file` lives, `nullify` just forgets where `file` lives.

Java is slightly confusing in this regard as it passes object references **by value**. This means that when you pass on your reference to another method it create a copy of the reference and passes that copy.

This means that if you carry out actions on the reference (such as `File.setExecutable()`) the actions will happen on the referenced object. If you change the reference itself, i.e. reassign it, then this only affects the local copy.

`final` only prevents the reassignment of a reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you change `object` var you do not change `file` var - Java passes arguments by value not by reference

Answer (score 0):

The `nullify` function (or any other function for that matter) receives a **reference** to an objects, and then changes **the reference** by assigning `null` to it.
It does not change the original object or the original reference to the object, so the fact that was `final` is inconsequential.

Answer (score 0):

```
       public String getLogIdentifierFromFile(final File file) {
          //this.file = null //Gives compiler error as obviously expected
              nullify(file);
           return "";
          } 

         public void nullify(final Object object) {
          object = null; //this will produce error

          }
```